# How can I join two tables on a REGEX match in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I have a table called `flights` where the `reservationNum` column is the confirmation number for each flight booking (an 8 digit number)

I have a table named `sentEmails` where the `body` column is the body of the email that was sent. The 8 digit confirmation number of the booking the email is for is in the text stored in the `body` column.

I need to pull all rows from `sentEmails` where the subject contains `Some text` but I also need some other info that is in the `flights` table row associated with that booking

I thought I might be able to join the tables on a regex match like the below:

```
Select *
from sentEmails se 
join flights f on f.reservationNum = se.body REGEXP '\d{8}'
where subject like '%Some text%'
and sentDate > '2016-02-01'
```

For the first row this *seems* to work giving info from both tables. Unfortunately, the data from `flights` is not correct and after that first row all of the remaining rows have the same `sentEmails` data and no data for the `flights` columns

**Is it possible to join two tables on a REGEX match in MySQL? And If not, how can I retrieve the desired data?**

**Note** Given the standardized content in the emails I can be 100% sure that the only 8 digit number each contains is the one I need

Comment: It would be better to create a temporary table containing the information you need to join with.  That regex is going to perform miserably.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do it such way. Cause you have no 100% garanty what 8 digits in email would be a confirmation number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's a totally fair point, can you show me how to do that? I cant figure out how to actually get ahold of the confirmation number out of the email so I can work with it and that is the only thing the 2 tables share in common

Comment: @SiZE Given the standardized content in the email I can be 100% sure that the only 8 digit number it contains is the one I need

Comment: It's always in the same place in the email?  Hit it with a parser, and put the number in another column of the table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is always in the same place. Im not sure what you mean though. I can export the data from the `sentEmails` parse out the confirmation numbers with PHP or JavaScript, concatenate them all into a long IN statement like `IN ('12345678','23456789',......)`, run that on the `flights` table then combine the data in Excel (ive resorted to this before when the data I needed was in a stored JSON string) but I feel like this is not what you have in mind. Sorry SQL is not my strong suit

Comment: Basically, I'm saying that you need to find a way to isolate the number in the email and put it in its own column in the table.  The join will then become trivial.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah gottcha, and I totally agree, our department doesnt have write access to this particular table but I have requested that the responsible team add a column for this (not the first time we've had this issue), the ticket is in, but no telling when it'll actually change :(

Comment: Tell them how much it's going to cost them to half-ass it with a regex (it's in the thousands of dollars), and perhaps they'll expedite your request.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should specify that this isnt going into any production code or anything, it's just to pull some data I need to investigate a possible bug in one of the systems that stores it's sent emails here.  For the department that owns this table and their normal uses (really simplistic), the sent-to email is sufficient to do what they need. The issue for me is that each email could map to multiple reservations and without the confirmation # I cant filter out the emails for reservations I dont want. They'll add it, but when they get to it ..... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE reservationNum=(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(body, pos-7, 8)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            GREATEST(
                LOCATE('0', body),
                LOCATE('1', body),
                LOCATE('2', body),
                LOCATE('3', body),
                LOCATE('4', body),
                LOCATE('5', body),
                LOCATE('6', body),
                LOCATE('7', body),
                LOCATE('8', body),
                LOCATE('9', body)
            ) as pos,
            body
        FROM
            sentEmails
    ) q
)
```

If you know position you can set it manualy or you can use UDF like this one https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

UPDATED

```
SELECT * FROM flights f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(body, pos-7, 8) sub
    FROM (
        SELECT
            GREATEST(
                LOCATE('0', body),
                LOCATE('1', body),
                LOCATE('2', body),
                LOCATE('3', body),
                LOCATE('4', body),
                LOCATE('5', body),
                LOCATE('6', body),
                LOCATE('7', body),
                LOCATE('8', body),
                LOCATE('9', body)
            ) as pos,
            body
        FROM
            sentEmails
    ) q1
) q2 ON (q2.sub=f.reservationNum)
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but when I run it I get `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: I changed `reservationNum=` to `reservationNum IN` but I have the same issue as my first attempt, first row returns wrong data and all the others are blank

Comment: Same as before, first row returns wrong data and all the others are blank, Im headed home for the night but Ill look at it again tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DelightedD0D Run subquery getting `sub` what it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem -- You need to cleanse the data *before* inserting it into the database.  That is, discover the 'number' and extract it when you get the `body`.  Then tag the record with the number(s).  This probably involve another table with tags (flight numbers) and ids of the record they were found in.

Even if you can concoct a REGEXP, it will be slooow because you must check *all* rows *every* time.